# How to identify reorderable code? Code reordering problems (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc817398.aspx) stated that:

> processors are free to reorder this code

```
internal static volatile int s_x = 0;
internal static volatile int s_y = 0;
internal static volatile int s_ya = 0;

void ThreadA() {
    s_x = 1;
    s_ya = s_y;
}
```

I am worried if any code could be reordered, and I know how to identify reorderable code. Specially about this piece of my code:

```
Processing.Add(ItemNumber, null);
AsyncTask.Begin(InternalRequestCallback, Remove, ItemNumber);
```

It must occur in the specified order or else it fails. Should I put a Thread.MemoryBarrier(); between those statements?

Comment: If you are concerned about code re-ordering you are either creating some funky and hard to understand and maintain code, or else you probably don't need to worry about it. Can you explain why you think the code snippet you supplied will be reordered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: no.

You code simply perform two invokes; the runtime guarantees that those methods will execute (on a single thread, at least) in sequence.

The complexity of the article centred around the complexities of **2** threads accessing shared state (you need the `ThreadB` method for the example to make sense). The code you have pasted is, I'm pretty sure, not re-orderable - not least because this is successive instructions (on dependent data) on the same thread.

You'd need to get a lot deeper than I understand to go into the full details. But unless you're doing something complex with lock-free, threaded programming, this is not likely to bite you.